# copy data from one sheet to another

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

Excel 2010: I'm trying to copy data from one sheet to another sheet using criteria 1: the cell in column a is not blank, and criteria 2: the cell in column b is a specific value. I tried the IF and VLOOKUP functions but end up with blank rows inbetween. All ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Part of current spreadsheet:

```
     A            B          C
1  CD_WR     CD_STATUS    CD_RQMT
2  1000          90        120
3  1001          50        110
4  1002          80        785
5  1003          60        612
```

Sheet tabs are: Main, Status 50, Status 60, Status 70, etc.

Comment: This could be done with formulas alone, but in my opinion, would be *pretty complicated*. Are you able to use macros?

Comment: filter cols a and b for what you want, click on a visible cell, click ctrl+shift+* then hit f5, go to "special..." and click visible cells only, then copy and paste!

Comment: because just copy/paste with hidden cells will copy all the hidden cells as well

Answer (score 2):

1.Apply both of your criteria

2.Color the selection to some color (say "yellow")

3.Remove the filter

4.The Sort as per Color yellow(all yellow cells shall come together)

5.Copy all the yellow cells

6.Paste them to another sheet

If you want the original order in the original sheet to be maintained,then.

1.Create a column with Sr.No and have a serial number in chronological order for all line itemss.

2.Perform step 1 to 6 as above

3.Sort as per ascending order in the Sr.No